# squid, ufw and iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid, ufw

I have a Ubuntu box with Squid installed acting as a transparent proxy server. The config which does the magic is the following. (eth0 is external interface and eth1 is internal.)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --jump MASQUERADE --source 192.168.0.0/24
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

At this point the proxy works fine.

Then i need to filter out some packets so I use ufw. i.e.

```
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo deny 5223/tcp
sudo ufw enable
```

At this point nothing works anymore. Not sure what I am missing. Should i do anything with port 3128? Am I having issues because I have two interfaces? Trying the hardest to wrap my head around this but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using iptables directly instead of using ufw. Seems like ufw by default creates a catch-all which i didn't need in my case.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --destination-port 5223 -i eth1
```

Comment: Yes, if you're already at the point where you're working with iptables, it's best just to stay there. IMHO, ufw is a feeble attempt and doesn't work for anything that isn't a single-NIC box.